# pandas how to filter out the next row of the row corresponding to the specified column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this：

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataA = [["2005-1-20", 5], ["2005-1-26", 8], ["2005-1-29", 7],
    ["2005-2-11",4], ["2005-2-18", 2],
    ["2005-2-21", 2], ["2005-3-11",3], ["2005-3-25", 4],
    ["2005-6-1",4], ["2005-6-15",5],
    ["2005-9-2", 12], ["2005-9-13",13], ["2005-10-11",14],
    ["2005-11-2",14], ["2005-11-17",15]]

dataB = [["2005-1-26", 5], ["2005-3-11",2]]

dfa= pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["date", "Vala"])

dfb= pd.DataFrame(data = dataB, columns=["date", "Valb"])
```

```
dfa                    dfb                                 dfc

       date   Vala     date    Valb                      date      Vala
0   2005-1-20   5  
1   2005-1-26   8 --- 2005-1-26  5 
2   2005-1-29   7 ----------------------------> i want   2005-1-29  7
3   2005-2-11   4
4   2005-2-18   2
5   2005-2-21   2
6   2005-3-11   3 --- 2005-3-11  2
7   2005-3-25   4 ----------------------------> i want  2005-3-25   4
8   2005-6-1    4
9   2005-6-15   5
10  2005-9-2    12
11  2005-9-13   13
12  2005-10-11  14
13  2005-11-2   14
14  2005-11-17  15
```

base on two datafram  dfa and dfb, i want to get dfc from dfa, dfc is composed of the next row of the row corresponding to the date of dfb and dfa ， how to do  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st convert the dates into datetime. Try to get the index where the date is in the list of date i.e `dfb.date` and in order to get the next row just shift it by 1 and fill na with False.

try:

```
dfa.date=pd.to_datetime(dfa.date)
dfb.date=pd.to_datetime(dfb.date)
dfc = dfa[dfa.date.isin(dfb.date).shift(1).fillna(False)]
```

**dfc:**

```
    date    Vala
2   2005-01-29  7
7   2005-03-25  4
```